# Reading a vector from multiple threads

Tags: rust

I have a function that returns a vector of strings, which is read by multiple threads later. How to do this in rust?

```
  fn get_list() -> Vec<String> { ... }
  fn read_vec() { 
       let v = get_list();
       for i in 1..10 {
           handles.push(thread::spawn (|| { do_work(&v); }));
       }
       handles.join();
  }
```

I think I need to extend the lifetime of v to static and pass it as a immutable ref to threads. But, I am not sure , how?

Comment: The answer is "use an Arc". It will guarantee that a) the vec will be kept alive until all threads finish b) that it will be cleaned up afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the threads spawned by `thread::spawn` run for an unknown amount of time. You'll need to make sure that your `Vec<String>` outlives these threads.

- You can use atomic reference-counting by creating an `Arc<Vec<String>>`, and create a `clone` for each thread. The `Vec<String>` will be deallocated only when all `Arc`s are dropped. [Docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html)
- You can `leak` the `Vec<String>`. I personally like this approach, but **only** if you need the `Vec<String>` for the entire runtime of your program. To achieve this, you can turn your `Vec<String>` into a `&'static [String]` by using `Vec::leak`. [Docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.leak)
- You can ensure that your threads will not run after the `read_vec` function returns - This is what you're essentially doing by calling `handles.join()`. However, the compiler doesn't see that these threads are joined later, and there might be edge cases where they are not joined (what happens when the 2nd `thread::spawn` panics?). To make this explicit, use the `scope` function in `std::thread`. [Docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html)
- Of course, you can also just `clone` the `Vec<String>`, and give each thread a unique copy.

**TL;DR:**
For this particular use-case, I'd recommend [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html). If the `Vec<String>` lives for the entire duration of your program, `leak`ing it using [`Vec::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.leak) is a great and often under-used solution. For more complex scenarios, wrapping the `Vec<String>` in an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) is probably the right way to go.

Comment: Thank you. well explained. Why I have to clone an Arc? Shouldn't a copy of Arc increase the refcount automatically?

Comment: @sanjivgupta I used `clone` as in [`std::clone::Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html). In Rust, you use `std::marker::Copy` to copy a value bit-by-bit, while `std::clone::Clone::clone` may perform more stuff than just a bitwise copy - for example, incrementing the refcount, like in `Arc`.

Comment: As you can see in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), `Arc` implements `Clone`, but it's not `Copy`.

Comment: Thank you again.  The thing I needed to know is "A copy in rust is bitwise copy, while clone can do the right stuff". I come from a c++ background where the copy of shared_ptr increments the refcount.

Comment: @sanjivgupta Ah, I see. Yeah, the memory semantics are different from c++. Assigning a value (`let x = y`) or passing it by value is a move, like `std::move` in c++. `Copy` in Rust changes that, and the old value stays valid. `Clone`, on the other hand, is just a normal method, used in Rust where you'd use a copy constructor in c++.

Comment: This great talk goes into this difference, if you want to understand this more deeply: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPmRDS0OSxM